# How prove this $|ON|\le \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

Tags: geometry

let ellipse $M:\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$,and there two point $A,B$ on $\partial M$,and the point $C\in AB$ ,such $AC=BC$,and the Circle $C$ is directly for the AB circle,for any point $N$ on $\partial C$,
show that
$$|ON|\le\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

[image]

my try: let 
$$A(x_{1},y_{1}),B(x_{2},y_{2}),C(\dfrac{x_{1}+x_{2}}{2},\dfrac{y_{1}+y_{2}}{2})$$
then
$$\dfrac{x^2_{1}}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2_{1}}{b^2}=1,\dfrac{x^2_{2}}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2_{2}}{b^2}=1$$
so the circle $C$ equation is 
$$\left(x-\dfrac{x_{1}+x_{2}}{2}\right)^2+\left(y-\dfrac{y_{1}+y_{2}}{2}\right)^2=r^2$$
where
$$4r^2=(x_{1}-x_{2})^2+(y_{1}-y_{2})^2$$
let $N(c,d)$,then
$$\left(c-\dfrac{x_{1}+x_{2}}{2}\right)^2+\left(d-\dfrac{y_{1}+y_{2}}{2}\right)^2=r^2$$
How prove
$$c^2+d^2\le a^2+b^2?$$

Thank you

Comment: Note that the maximum of $|ON|$ is attained when $ON$ passes through $C$. So you just need to show that $|OC|+|AC|\leq\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following Tian's observation and taking
$$A:(a\cos\theta,b\sin\theta),$$
$$B:(a\cos\phi,b\sin\phi)$$
we have to prove
$$4\|OC\|^2+8\|OC\|\|AC\|+4\|AC\|^2\leq 4a^2+4b^2,\tag{1} $$
or:
$$a^2(\cos\theta+\cos\phi)^2+b^2(\sin\theta+\sin\phi)^2+a^2(\cos\theta-\cos\phi)^2+b^2(\sin\theta-\sin\phi)^2+2\sqrt{\left(a^2(\cos\theta+\cos\phi)^2+b^2(\sin\theta+\sin\phi)^2\right)\cdot\left(a^2(\cos\theta-\cos\phi)^2+b^2(\sin\theta-\sin\phi)^2\right)}\leq 4a^2+4b^2,\tag{2}$$
equivalent to:
$$\sqrt{\left(a^2(\cos\theta+\cos\phi)^2+b^2(\sin\theta+\sin\phi)^2\right)\cdot\left(a^2(\cos\theta-\cos\phi)^2+b^2(\sin\theta-\sin\phi)^2\right)}\leq a^2(\sin^2\theta+\sin^2\phi)+b^2(\cos^2\theta+\cos^2\phi),\tag{3}$$
and to:
$$a^4\left(\sin^2\theta-\sin^2\phi\right)^2+b^4\left(\cos^2\theta-\cos^2\phi\right)^2+a^2b^2\left(\sin(2\theta)-\sin(2\phi)\right)^2\leq a^4(\sin^2\theta+\sin^2\phi)^2+b^4(\cos^2\theta+\cos^2\phi)^2+2a^2b^2(\sin^2\theta+\sin^2\phi)(\cos^2\theta+\cos^2\phi),\tag{4}$$
that further reduces to:
$$4a^2 b^2(\sin\theta\cos\theta-\sin\phi\cos\phi)^2\leq 4a^4\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi+4b^4\cos^2\theta\cos^2\phi+2a^2b^2(\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\phi\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\theta\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi\cos^2\theta),\tag{5} $$
and finally to:
$$2a^2 b^2(\sin^2\theta-\sin^2\phi)(\cos^2\theta-\cos^2\phi)\leq 4(a^2\sin\theta\sin\phi+b^2\cos\theta\cos\phi)^2\tag{6} $$
that is trivial since the LHS is non-positive while the RHS is non-negative.

Answer (score 3):

[Jack](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/44121/jack-daurizio) has already written quite an answer to this problem, but I couldn't believe that it didn't have more elegant solution. As my sense of beauty didn't leave me at peace, I couldn't help but find some geometrical ideas behind this problem. I must also add that I really enjoyed solving it.

As Tian has already [noted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668125/how-prove-this-on-le-sqrta2b2#comment1404443_668125), it suffices to show that $OC + CA \leqslant \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.

Let's reflect points $A$, $B$ and $C$ across the point $O$. We get a parallelogram $ABA'B'$ and the desired sum $\color{green}{OC + CA}$ equals to $\frac{1}{4}$ of the perimeter of $ABA'B'$ (since $CC'$ is the middle line of $ABA'B'$).

[image: image #1 here]

So we want to show that perimeter of parallelogram inscribed in an ellipse is not bigger than $4\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.

In other words, it would be great if we knew how to maximize the perimeter of such a parallelogram. Fortunately, humanity knows how to solve this problem, namely:

> Among all the parallelograms inscribed in a given ellipse
>   those of maximal perimeter have the property that any point on the ellipse is the vertex of exactly one.

(paraphrasing result of [this article](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/amm/114/fulltext.pdf))

Moreover, according to `Lemma` from that article, the parallelogram has maximal perimeter *iff* tangent lines at adjacent vertices are perpendicular to each other.

[image: image #2 here]

This leads us to the final fact that the maximum perimeter in originally stated problem is $4\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ because choosing point $A$ so that it lies on the coordinate axis produces exactly rhombus with a side equal to $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.

Comment: It's not surprising since it is a well-known fact that the locus of points that "see" an ellipse under a right angle is a circle with radius $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, and the orthogonality condition probably arises from the Lagrange conditions when finding the maximum perimeter through Lagrange multipliers. Very nice, anyway.